# Does Appium supports Apple watch?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, apple-watch, appium-ios, wearables

Is it possible to do Automation testing in Apple Watch or wearable devices using Appium?
If NO, is there any alternate way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

No: Appium [does not currently support Apple Watch](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4829#issuecomment-388039432).

It is apparently possible through xcode: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-apple-watch-development/issues/39

Answer (score -2):

Yes , Appium does support Apple watch.

First, you can connect the gadget through ADB just like you connect to a phone/tablet:

$ adb devices

Also, connecting wearable with phone/device through Bluetooth is easy and straightforward:

$ adb -s forward tcp:4444 localabstract:adb-hub/ && adb -s connect localhost:4444

Then, you start Appium server (if using Appium locally) and start the test run targeting to http://localhost:/wd/hub/

$ appium -U localhost:4444

After this, test script is getting executed.

For more information kindly go to the link below.

https://bitbar.com/app-development-and-testing-on-wearables/

Comment: You mixed up Android and Apple Watch. Apple Watch has nothing to do with ADB.